# Debugging the .getWeights in R BGVAR package

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm stuck trying to figure out why the bgvar function won't start with my data. When I call

```
modzs <- bgvar(Data = Data,W = W)
```

the error is

```
Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : 
  length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent
```

which apparently indicates and inappropriately short list of names for an array.

The `traceback()` report in RStudio suggests that execution halts at

```
3: `rownames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = colnames(endonr))
2: .getweights(Data = Data, W = W, OE.weights = OE.weights, Wex.restr = Wex.restr, 
       variable.list = variable.list)
1: bgvar(Data, W)
```

So I opened the [source repository](https://github.com/cran/BGVAR/blob/master/R/utils.R) for that part of the package, copied the code for `getweights` and tried to execute it line by line.

It throws the error:

```
> cnames <- names(Data)
> W      <- lapply(W,function(x) x[cnames,cnames])
Error in x[cnames, cnames] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

which is probably why I get that `dimnames` error on bgvar launch but it makes no sense because my W is a 15x15 matrix and Data is a list of 15 entities. There should not be  mismatch.

My R session with the data pre-loaded is [here](https://easyupload.io/1ik2d7). It's got the data pre-loaded. The code that I execute is mostly copied from that utils.R link. I provide it below (obviously includes loading of the BGVAR package).

```
library("BGVAR")
W
Data

q <- bgvar(Data, W)

OE.weights <- NULL

W <- W[,-1]
rownames(W) <- names(Data)
colnames(W) <- names(Data)
storage.mode(W) <- "numeric"


cN<-names(Data) # ord
nn<-lapply(Data,colnames)
exo=which(table(unlist(nn))==1) #exo variables are those that are only in one country model
endo<-which(!table(unlist(nn))==1)
exo.countries<-names(which(sapply(lapply(nn,function(y) names(exo)%in%y),any))) #gives you a vector of exo countries
OE.flag <- FALSE

W.sets<-length(W)
if(is.null(variable.list)){
  variable.list<-list();variable.list$vars<-names(endo)
}

#------------------------------------- additional checks -----------------------------------------------------#
if(is.list(W)&&length(W)>1){
  if(is.null(variable.list)){
    stop("You have submitted more than 1 weight matrix but not specified the according variable sets.")
  }
  if(length(W)!=length(variable.list)){
    stop("You have submitted more than 1 weight matrix but not the same number of variable sets.")
  }
  if(!all(names(endo)%in%unlist(variable.list))){
    stop("You have submitted more than 1 weight matrix but some of the variables are not assigned to a weight matrix by the variable list")
  }
}
if(!is.null(OE.weights)){
  OE.flag <- TRUE
  OE.sets <- length(OE.weights)
  OE.cN   <- names(OE.weights)
  OE.vars <- lapply(OE.weights,function(l)l$variables)
  OE <- list()
  for(kk in 1:OE.sets){
    OE[[OE.cN[kk]]] <- Data[[OE.cN[kk]]]
    Data[[OE.cN[kk]]] <- NULL
  }
  if(!all(unlist(lapply(OE.vars,function(l)l%in%c(names(exo),names(endo)))))){
    stop("Please specify for the additional entities variables which are also contained in the data. Please respecify.")
  }
  OE.exo <- lapply(OE.weights,function(l)l$exo)
  for(kk in 1:OE.sets){
    if(is.null(OE.exo[[kk]])) OE.exo[[kk]] <- colnames(OE[[kk]])
  }
  if(!any(sapply(1:OE.sets,function(oo)any(OE.exo[[oo]]%in%OE.vars[[oo]])))){
    stop("Please specify the exogenous variables also in the element 'variables'. Please respecify.")
  }
  OE.weights <- lapply(OE.weights,function(l)l$weights)
  if(any(unlist(lapply(OE.weights,function(l)is.null(names(l))||!all(names(l)%in%names(Data)))))){
    stop("Either you have not provided names attached to the weights of other entities or the ones you are provided are not contained in the country data. Please respecify.")
  }
}
#------------------------------------- build W matrix -----------------------------------------------------#
#make sure that W and Data names are in the same order

cnames
W

cnames <- names(Data)
W      <- lapply(W,function(x) x[cnames,cnames])

length(colnames(W))
length(Data)
length(rownames(W))

xglobal <- c()
for(jj in 1:length(Data)){
  pretemp <- Data[[jj]];class(pretemp) <- "numeric"
  temp <- as.matrix(pretemp[,colSums(is.na(pretemp))<nrow(pretemp)])
  colnames(temp) <- paste(cnames[jj],colnames(pretemp),sep=".")
  xglobal <- cbind(xglobal,temp)
}

Max.char<-max(nchar(colnames(xglobal)))
cnt.char<-max(nchar(cnames))
# for each country
gW<-list()
for(cc in 1:length(cnames)){
  xglobal <- xglobal[,!duplicated(colnames(xglobal))]
  #creates a dynamic list of variables
  varnames <- substr(colnames(xglobal),cnt.char+2,Max.char); varnames <- varnames[!duplicated(varnames)] 
  
  if(!is.null(Wex.restr)){
    varnames = varnames[-charmatch(Wex.restr,varnames)]
  }
  
  # names of endo variables
  endnames <- unlist(lapply(strsplit(colnames(xglobal)[grepl(cnames[[cc]],colnames(xglobal))],".",fixed=TRUE),
                            function(l)l[2]))
  Wnew <- matrix(0,length(varnames),ncol(xglobal));colnames(Wnew) <- colnames(xglobal);rownames(Wnew) <- varnames
  
  #----------------------here we specify the part for the weakly exogenous variabes-------------------------------------#
  # loop over all variables
  for (kk in 1:nrow(Wnew)){
    # gives you name of countries with this specific variable
    var.cntry.indic <- substr(colnames(Wnew),4,Max.char)==rownames(Wnew)[kk]
    cntry.indic     <- substr(names(Wnew[kk,var.cntry.indic]),1,2)
    if(length(cntry.indic)>0){
      # this selects the weight matrix according to the variable we want to weight (financial, real, etc)
      wghts <- W[[which(sapply(variable.list, function(x) rownames(Wnew)[kk] %in% x))]][cc,]
      # this gives the variable name (e.g., y)
      Wnew[kk,var.cntry.indic] <- wghts[cntry.indic]
    }else{# in case we have exo variables
      # this includes the exo variables in all country models and the exo countries
      Wnew[kk,var.cntry.indic] <- 1
      # in case we look at an exo country, where the variable is endog. defined, we have to set the exo variable to zero
      if(cnames[[cc]]%in%exo.countries&&paste(cnames[cc],rownames(Wnew)[kk],sep=".")%in%colnames(Wnew)){
        Wnew[kk,var.cntry.indic] <- 0
      }
      
    }
  }
  #----------------------here we specify the part for the endogenous variabes-----------------------------------------#
  endoW <- matrix(0,length(endnames),ncol(Wnew))
  endonr <- xglobal[,substr(colnames(xglobal),1,2)==cnames[cc]];rownames(endoW) <- colnames(endonr)
  colnames(endoW) <- colnames(Wnew)
  namesW <- colnames(endoW)
  namesNr <- colnames(endonr)
  
  for (j in 1:nrow(endoW)){
    for (i in 1:length(namesW)){
      if(namesNr[[j]]==namesW[[i]]){
        endoW[j,i]=1
      }
    }
  }
  WfinNR <- rbind(endoW,Wnew)
  
  WfinNR <- WfinNR[!(rowSums(abs(WfinNR)) == 0),]
  gW[[cc]]<-apply(WfinNR,2,function(x) x/(rowSums(WfinNR)))
}
names(gW)<-cnames
gW
cnames
#----------------------here we specify the part for extra weights-----------------------------------------#
if(OE.flag){
  for(kk in 1:OE.sets){
    temp    <- OE[[kk]];class(temp) <- "numeric"
    xglobal <- cbind(xglobal,temp);OE.x<-ncol(OE[[kk]]); OEnames <- colnames(OE[[kk]])
    colnames(xglobal)[(ncol(xglobal)-OE.x+1):ncol(xglobal)] <- paste(OE.cN[kk],".",OEnames,sep="")
    
    for(i in 1:length(cnames)){
      aux<-gW[[cnames[i]]];ii<-nrow(aux)
      aux<-rbind(cbind(aux,matrix(0,ncol=OE.x,nrow=nrow(aux))),matrix(0,nrow=length(OE.exo[[kk]]),ncol=c(ncol(aux)+OE.x)))
      rownames(aux)[(ii+1):(ii+length(OE.exo[[kk]]))]<-OE.exo[[kk]]
      colnames(aux)[(ncol(aux)-OE.x+1):ncol(aux)]<-paste(OE.cN[kk],OEnames,sep=".")
      if(length(OE.exo[[kk]])>1){
        diag(aux[OE.exo[[kk]],paste(OE.cN[kk],".",OE.exo[[kk]],sep="")])<-1
      }else{
        aux[OE.exo[[kk]],paste(OE.cN[kk],".",OE.exo[[kk]],sep="")]<-1
      }
      gW[[cnames[i]]]<-aux
    }
    # this creates the W matrix for the other entity model
    if(!is.null(OE.vars[[kk]])){
      Wnew <- matrix(0,length(OE.vars[[kk]]),ncol(xglobal))
      colnames(Wnew) <- colnames(xglobal)
      rownames(Wnew) <- c(paste(OE.cN[kk],".",OE.vars[[kk]][!OE.vars[[kk]]%in%names(endo)],sep=""),
                          OE.vars[[kk]][OE.vars[[kk]]%in%names(endo)])
      if(OE.x>1){
        diag(Wnew[paste(OE.cN[kk],".",OEnames,sep=""),paste(OE.cN[kk],".",OEnames,sep="")])<-1
      }else{
        Wnew[paste(OE.cN[kk],".",OEnames,sep=""),paste(OE.cN[kk],".",OEnames,sep="")]<-1
      }
      vars <- OE.vars[[kk]][OE.vars[[kk]]%in%names(endo)]
      for(i in 1:length(vars)){
        Wnew[vars[i],paste(names(OE.weights[[kk]]),".",vars[i],sep="")] <- OE.weights[[kk]]
        Wnew[vars[i],]
      }
      # this creates the part if there are more than one other entities
      if(OE.sets>1 && kk < OE.sets){
        aux <- Wnew
        xx <- lapply(OE[(kk+1):OE.sets],function(l)ncol(l))
        xx <- sum(unlist(xx[!OE.cN%in%OE.cN[(kk+1):OE.sets]]))
        names <- c()
        for(kkk in (kk+1):OE.sets){
          names <- c(names,paste(OE.cN[kkk],".",colnames(OE[[kkk]]),sep=""))
        }
        Wnew <- cbind(aux,matrix(0,ncol=xx,nrow=nrow(aux)))
        colnames(Wnew)[(ncol(Wnew)-xx+1):ncol(Wnew)] <- names
      }
      gW[[(length(gW)+1)]]  <- Wnew
      names(gW)[length(gW)] <- OE.cN[kk]
    }
  }
}
#----------------------- return everything to main function ---------------------------------------------#
gW<-gW[cN]
return(list(gW=gW,bigx=xglobal,exo=exo,exo.countries=exo.countries,endo=endo))
}
```

I have already checked that names in Data and W are the same and go in the same order. What are other reasons why the code may not be working?

Edit: abridged data (dput() output)

```
list(AU = structure(c(82.26542, 76.90665, 81.3056, 13.3278529605016, 
13.2675314934202, 14.08287406905, 1.57492049199085, 1.53241145743146, 
1.53703787878788, 687779.1, 690014.4, 698007.9, 15.4186513303132, 
15.7887207126198, 16.3593905194588, 5.31813882533333, 5.813293651, 
6.27242424233333, 21.6562684866715, 22.2824426507816, 22.7961576160219
), dim = c(3L, 7L), dimnames = list(NULL, c("CPI", "EXP", "FXR", 
"GDP", "IMP", "LTR", "MBR")), index = structure(c(917740800, 
925430400, 933379200), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts", 
"zoo")), BR = structure(c(122.0008, 118.3568, 121.3928, 11.4663652061975, 
12.0036792773981, 11.5188000894012, 1.76999944444444, 1.71353391812866, 
1.85892121212121, 1888531.9, 1896246, 1898302.3, 12.0720366715372, 
12.7649682308787, 12.2797300986907, 12.84, 13.48, 14.05, 8.37557145311969, 
8.80096626575696, 9.2219031051324), dim = c(3L, 7L), dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("CPI", "EXP", "FXR", "GDP", "IMP", "LTR", "MBR")), index = structure(c(917740800, 
925430400, 933379200), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts", 
"zoo")), CA = structure(c(95.6446, 96.81783, 98.2313, 56.5147700547161, 
58.2006505998734, 60.9462095084936, 1.51118672302738, 1.47301513708514, 
1.48561146461905, 1113890.4, 1123208.6, 1140783.2, 51.3699660110776, 
53.0084007132572, 54.0430206460317, 5.09697826086957, 5.32331096681097, 
5.65603174603175, 31.0106333689699, 31.5177272859839, 31.961391384168
), dim = c(3L, 7L), dimnames = list(NULL, c("CPI", "EXP", "FXR", 
"GDP", "IMP", "LTR", "MBR")), index = structure(c(917740800, 
925430400, 933379200), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts", 
"zoo")), CH = structure(c(94.26778, 97.00242, 95.68923, 19.05200132798, 
18.2208427948728, 18.9420780347153, 1.42636358695652, 1.51443228715729, 
1.52747196775758, 18.9725459040406, 17.9508938635398, 18.9808202320066, 
2.56966666666667, 2.73033333333333, 3.21333333333333, 49.7735085441036, 
50.0841532380439, 50.2953552933618), dim = c(3L, 6L), dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("CPI", "EXP", "FXR", "IMP", "LTR", "MBR")), index = structure(c(917740800, 
925430400, 933379200), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts", 
"zoo")), CN = structure(c(58.0546, 57.23155, 58.45868, 43.5283183955028, 
45.7667027202633, 51.369022356663, 8.2787, 8.27856333333333, 
8.27743, 37.6837351837686, 41.3163600353252, 41.9422477435453, 
4.47663333333333, 4.47663333333333, 4.47663333333333, 8.06650416308289, 
8.34461339283924, 8.5574295507205), dim = c(3L, 6L), dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("CPI", "EXP", "FXR", "IMP", "LTR", "MBR")), index = structure(c(917740800, 
925430400, 933379200), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts", 
"zoo")), EA = structure(c(117.6876, 118.4051, 119.1685, 209.838005174791, 
206.344334864423, 214.310007179154, 0.890865035412319, 0.946297424241702, 
0.953590795030303, 11401409.4, 11461237.1, 11598799, 204.666656461184, 
201.047372041002, 210.300905832237, 3.9924, 4.25743333333333, 
5.0507, 42.0528902876188, 42.5438693283613, 42.950682509578), dim = c(3L, 
7L), dimnames = list(NULL, c("CPI", "EXP", "FXR", "GDP", "IMP", 
"LTR", "MBR")), index = structure(c(917740800, 925430400, 933379200
), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts", "zoo")), 
    IL = structure(c(111.1162, 111.1162, 111.1162, 5.09757871712443, 
    5.4592682123013, 5.96892630789915, 4.06122011732229, 4.08691197691198, 
    4.18112121212121, 163284.8, 168668.4, 169290, 7.10997117053671, 
    7.406586771916, 7.9197374186323, 5.21, 5.09333333333333, 
    5.21666666666667, 22.8002029860775, 23.805787468422, 24.8224859629471
    ), dim = c(3L, 7L), dimnames = list(NULL, c("CPI", "EXP", 
    "FXR", "GDP", "IMP", "LTR", "MBR")), index = structure(c(917740800, 
    925430400, 933379200), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts", 
    "zoo")), IN = structure(c(70.86469, 69.57063, 70.92097, 8.39952864029184, 
    8.44018422538691, 9.52468309974898, 42.4695966666667, 42.8780733333333, 
    43.4284866666667, 2268598.5, 2327179, 2356160, 10.5690361503223, 
    10.7008370773947, 12.9287236978616, 8.26716666666667, 8.26716666666667, 
    8.26716666666667, 8.8035303879122, 9.13320603099139, 9.49252426345693
    ), dim = c(3L, 7L), dimnames = list(NULL, c("CPI", "EXP", 
    "FXR", "GDP", "IMP", "LTR", "MBR")), index = structure(c(917740800, 
    925430400, 933379200), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts", 
    "zoo")), JP = structure(c(185.5802, 205.3497, 183.9057, 98.9686430444595, 
    97.2352592101695, 107.217234836789, 116.523421052631, 120.902406078327, 
    113.598863636364, 4516739.7, 4533668.7, 4558343.4, 72.7857900351236, 
    72.0284287089008, 79.4308397025317, 1.94766666666667, 1.50966666666667, 
    1.78, 76.8403418311359, 77.4865630799908, 77.9800907004243
    ), dim = c(3L, 7L), dimnames = list(NULL, c("CPI", "EXP", 
    "FXR", "GDP", "IMP", "LTR", "MBR")), index = structure(c(917740800, 
    925430400, 933379200), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts", 
    "zoo")), KR = structure(c(102.7181, 100.7295, 104.8241, 32.2524721948081, 
    34.9171509637589, 36.2037447955411, 1192.05405797101, 1187.39287157287, 
    1195.16121212121, 915697.3, 955833.8, 982417.2, 25.8937480394644, 
    28.6686974235292, 30.4342735103449, 7.76333333333333, 7.76333333333333, 
    7.76333333333333, 27.2030286045815, 27.8539035746815, 28.2525780239985
    ), dim = c(3L, 7L), dimnames = list(NULL, c("CPI", "EXP", 
    "FXR", "GDP", "IMP", "LTR", "MBR")), index = structure(c(917740800, 
    925430400, 933379200), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts", 
    "zoo")), RU = structure(c(61.36739, 64.91503, 84.93548, 15.4860492644414, 
    15.9242307983476, 17.0560174296649, 22.8895, 24.4942333333333, 
    24.8239, 1742001.7, 1803740.1, 1839252.1, 9.09241637213071, 
    9.69047185843195, 9.0749258239904, 98.16, 90.6766666666667, 
    75.9933333333334, 1.41124672182256, 1.59329907965375, 1.78179645448887
    ), dim = c(3L, 7L), dimnames = list(NULL, c("CPI", "EXP", 
    "FXR", "GDP", "IMP", "LTR", "MBR")), index = structure(c(917740800, 
    925430400, 933379200), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts", 
    "zoo")), SA = structure(c(10.1824, 11.588, 13.3738666666667, 
    3.75, 3.75, 3.75, 1148504.3, 1148504.3, 1148504.3, 7.0808, 
    6.9392, 6.92773333333333), dim = 3:4, dimnames = list(NULL, 
        c("EXP", "FXR", "GDP", "IMP")), index = structure(c(917740800, 
    925430400, 933379200), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts", 
    "zoo")), TR = structure(c(67.63757, 70.3793, 72.74276, 6.890286218, 
    6.243196527, 6.530444188, 0.34168861884058, 0.395968412337662, 
    0.439352015151515, 910591.9, 905458.8, 890187.1, 9.391672566, 
    10.05122254, 10.22050927, 2.03618691787274, 2.45224466198878, 
    2.85152980194772), dim = c(3L, 6L), dimnames = list(NULL, 
        c("CPI", "EXP", "FXR", "GDP", "IMP", "MBR")), index = structure(c(917740800, 
    925430400, 933379200), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts", 
    "zoo")), UK = structure(c(90.00383, 87.55027, 87.51717, 64.5369466592794, 
    63.9992857837613, 68.4235909623759, 0.612205222913043, 0.622407689325758, 
    0.624305662727272, 2064137.7, 2072479.5, 2107310.2, 78.0951697878842, 
    75.4532585256608, 80.7567020375659, 4.45803333333333, 4.89013333333333, 
    5.49806666666667, 35.0503710971087, 35.1602570318163, 35.3874976284418
    ), dim = c(3L, 7L), dimnames = list(NULL, c("CPI", "EXP", 
    "FXR", "GDP", "IMP", "LTR", "MBR")), index = structure(c(917740800, 
    925430400, 933379200), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts", 
    "zoo")), US = structure(c(91.55647, 86.47107, 88.24854, 167.543, 
    169.468, 176.035, 12992931.6, 13101422.5, 13274757.9, 237.192, 
    249.869, 263.535, 4.98333333333333, 5.54, 5.88333333333333, 
    36.6954197142406, 37.2300769607558, 37.7854895351637, 264.333333333333, 
    253.75, 268.083333333333, 14.3103989361702, 18.295156626506, 
    22.3649880668258), dim = c(3L, 8L), dimnames = list(NULL, 
        c("CPI", "EXP", "GDP", "IMP", "LTR", "MBR", "WHT", "WTI"
        )), index = structure(c(917740800, 925430400, 933379200
    ), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts", "zoo"
    )))

structure(c(0, 0.007258397, 0.004384407, 0.007124473, 0.046937439, 
0.016027547, 0.007413191, 0.039915283, 0.059307258, 0.043306643, 
0.00172888, 0.007626772, 0.005573096, 0.013747509, 0.014358853, 
0.005843338, 0, 0.006594832, 0.008140664, 0.030819836, 0.023463688, 
0.011279637, 0.018533225, 0.012689312, 0.015664346, 0.012533901, 
0.015931198, 0.009508997, 0.007760516, 0.025719979, 0.0140926, 
0.021594124, 0, 0.011126088, 0.023385409, 0.022573649, 0.011143019, 
0.016084155, 0.023795867, 0.016364039, 0.003944071, 0.016867148, 
0.008167946, 0.023457056, 0.258992347, 0.010657658, 0.016580201, 
0.005491079, 0, 0.011315142, 0.104580939, 0.056779456, 0.057895386, 
0.012069034, 0.005796411, 0.028872631, 0.008545085, 0.030086389, 
0.037530141, 0.020293891, 0.29541545, 0.21235005, 0.07231354, 
0.05097169, 0, 0.03739433, 0.0713611, 0.16024703, 0.28559193, 
0.2961008, 0.15012195, 0.19670219, 0.07971904, 0.07721311, 0.1913896, 
0.14341162, 0.28888082, 0.06898971, 0.63380519, 0.20780404, 0, 
0.34392078, 0.23658324, 0.14555799, 0.13237178, 0.52763098, 0.16813418, 
0.49346108, 0.59132537, 0.22004493, 0.003238443, 0.005956027, 
0.001707756, 0.004608563, 0.004796915, 0.01827949, 0, 0.0159985, 
0.003137514, 0.003756785, 0.007008386, 1e-13, 0.01999201, 0.00527625, 
0.01447442, 0.03948706, 0.02485663, 0.00614089, 0.02541879, 0.02859312, 
0.01582243, 0.03790926, 0, 0.01375526, 0.02361541, 0.02002204, 
0.11864119, 0.02024388, 0.01622535, 0.0231229, 0.19705161, 0.051129, 
0.03127153, 0.03016873, 0.18225716, 0.09395666, 0.02823832, 0.04925955, 
0, 0.15915297, 0.04544574, 0.16467115, 0.02033042, 0.02784839, 
0.0996567, 0.083743087, 0.03629164, 0.013005784, 0.008077664, 
0.121588139, 0.023785858, 0.02106277, 0.044982132, 0.091134769, 
0, 0.038475866, 0.11478393, 0.024775274, 0.01294248, 0.045654965, 
0.002817707, 0.023071514, 0.0024476, 0.011303583, 0.036704451, 
0.02975208, 0.016255829, 0.023112611, 0.020704182, 0.025561642, 
0, 0.002831056, 0.111771946, 0.016490506, 0.011155943, 0.01022532, 
0.01913693, 0.003576951, 0.006503726, 0.02313183, 0.01198395, 
1e-12, 0.072994, 0.0415516, 0.04920629, 0.001863715, 0, 0.02051937, 
0.007694036, 0.0182116, 0.003622021, 0.00723971, 0.00228576, 
0.012022732, 0.007863642, 0.027084105, 0.037849027, 0.012945634, 
0.003264646, 0.008246546, 0.05239551, 0.016648586, 0, 0.017044619, 
0.006858711, 0.04911127, 0.02892588, 0.02747133, 0.07405134, 
0.032128, 0.31747091, 0.06570103, 0.05529758, 0.02602394, 0.02111569, 
0.04327837, 0.02200737, 0.06978965, 0, 0.05006517, 0.14128282, 
0.25672909, 0.75431882, 0.11667677, 0.24267487, 0.25782437, 0.29108658, 
0.19615167, 0.26141669, 0.19974064, 0.06667796, 0.14661014, 0.08606091, 
0.14544467, 0), dim = c(15L, 15L), dimnames = list(c("AU", "BR", 
"CA", "CH", "CN", "EA", "IL", "IN", "JP", "KR", "RU", "SA", "TR", 
"UK", "US"), c("AU", "BR", "CA", "CH", "CN", "EA", "IL", "IN", 
"JP", "KR", "RU", "SA", "TR", "UK", "US")))
```

Edit: below is dput() of a dataset produced with the same code but bgvar() works with it:

```
list(CN = structure(c(4.59, 3.24, 3.24, 3.24, 3.24, 3.24, 3.24, 
3.24, 3.24, 3.24, 3.24, 3.24, 2.7, 2.7, 2.7, 2.7, 2.7, 2.7, 2.7, 
8.06650416308289, 8.34461339283924, 8.5574295507205, 8.8416664184757, 
9.17299383383491, 9.43908106690589, 9.69503274624059, 9.97375186158891, 
10.3341289752455, 10.6807472746534, 11.3639676234721, 11.7061708798632, 
12.1322895358986, 12.5725745334781, 13.091436070924, 13.6849260958503, 
14.3713199075819, 15.0355125778046, 15.8370499740831, 98.566272, 
97.83291, 98.836061, 99.1672012, 100.1008965, 100.09692045, 100.2640063, 
100.9300591, 100.66374, 101.567239, 100.7926206, 99.8662782, 
99.4131021, 99.0086457, 99.2423089, 99.4068282, 100.4696215, 
100.6094389, 100.8069077), dim = c(19L, 3L), dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("IIR", "MBR", "CPI")), index = structure(c(915148800, 
922924800, 930787200, 938736000, 946684800, 954547200, 962409600, 
970358400, 978307200, 986083200, 993945600, 1001894400, 1009843200, 
1017619200, 1025481600, 1033430400, 1041379200, 1049155200, 1057017600
), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts", "zoo")), 
    EU = structure(c(2.9252, 2.5632, 2.4336, 3.0418, 3.5104, 
    4.2945, 4.5905, 4.8268, 4.7814, 4.5395, 3.9865, 3.3389, 3.264, 
    3.3485, 3.3186, 3.0945, 2.749, 2.2133, 2.0209, 42.0528902876188, 
    42.5438693283613, 42.950682509578, 43.5053683124797, 44.6424530671513, 
    45.3741172927471, 45.2717683632816, 45.551092571757, 47.3904685378504, 
    48.6113984962501, 49.2346889214365, 50.262830868842, 51.3018546794212, 
    52.1071597095362, 52.6113170748269, 53.674206164702, 55.014838189854, 
    56.4412582156259, 56.8227600227728, 100.90444, 101.021891, 
    101.184049, 101.579019, 102.005636, 101.96072, 102.265031, 
    102.529457, 102.157986, 102.955839, 102.434531, 102.144632, 
    102.56009, 102.112525, 102.106886, 102.300175, 102.31819, 
    101.997482, 102.0718), dim = c(19L, 3L), dimnames = list(
        NULL, c("IIR", "MBR", "CPI")), index = structure(c(915148800, 
    922924800, 930787200, 938736000, 946684800, 954547200, 962409600, 
    970358400, 978307200, 986083200, 993945600, 1001894400, 1009843200, 
    1017619200, 1025481600, 1033430400, 1041379200, 1049155200, 
    1057017600), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts", 
    "zoo")), RU = structure(c(60, 55, 55, 55, 33, 33, 28, 25, 
    25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 23, 21, 21, 18, 16, 16, 1.41124672182256, 
    1.59329907965375, 1.78179645448887, 1.97570468563864, 2.24040570450153, 
    2.52379975867993, 2.85068461482232, 3.21880745853885, 3.48527543523521, 
    3.78752721267999, 4.09204522240658, 4.47302782031843, 4.6842626885763, 
    4.9668169460222, 5.35451494946906, 5.78343580309854, 6.28162733303322, 
    6.8606313442598, 7.51108185634982, 202.6092, 216.8237, 198.22007, 
    147.46852, 125.43802, 119.83093, 118.73701, 119.78989, 122.19488, 
    124.41, 120.9723, 118.67606, 117.78062, 115.54778, 114.98511, 
    115.00793, 114.63042, 114.05352, 113.51224), dim = c(19L, 
    3L), dimnames = list(NULL, c("IIR", "MBR", "CPI")), index = structure(c(915148800, 
    922924800, 930787200, 938736000, 946684800, 954547200, 962409600, 
    970358400, 978307200, 986083200, 993945600, 1001894400, 1009843200, 
    1017619200, 1025481600, 1033430400, 1041379200, 1049155200, 
    1057017600), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts", 
    "zoo")), TR = structure(c(76.32, 76.91, 67.51, 69.97, 39.2, 
    43.05, 47.44, 183.2, 81.19, 63, 59.03, 59, 54.73, 48, 46, 
    44, 44, 38.23, 30.66, 2.03618691787274, 2.45224466198878, 
    2.85152980194772, 3.40383568191502, 4.02924500314335, 4.46950864742143, 
    4.88377331905386, 5.1592037849979, 5.96328891188708, 7.56154093609563, 
    8.71507793534991, 9.78655006771246, 9.81916170801812, 10.599320649388, 
    11.7940455732388, 12.1055918024629, 12.8023795093054, 12.7833858225293, 
    12.9848521657004, 164.42184, 163.69998, 164.87749, 166.06177, 
    168.82719, 161.65232, 152.65753, 142.31555, 135.63059, 152.29092, 
    158.59326, 167.45192, 170.32741, 147.04456, 139.45757, 131.60961, 
    126.53236, 125.86128, 121.06997), dim = c(19L, 3L), dimnames = list(
        NULL, c("IIR", "MBR", "CPI")), index = structure(c(915148800, 
    922924800, 930787200, 938736000, 946684800, 954547200, 962409600, 
    970358400, 978307200, 986083200, 993945600, 1001894400, 1009843200, 
    1017619200, 1025481600, 1033430400, 1041379200, 1049155200, 
    1057017600), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts", 
    "zoo")), US = structure(c(4.81, 4.76, 5.22, 5.3, 5.85, 6.53, 
    6.52, 6.4, 5.31, 3.97, 3.07, 1.82, 1.73, 1.75, 1.75, 1.24, 
    1.25, 1.22, 1.01, 36.6954197142406, 37.2300769607558, 37.7854895351637, 
    38.3004984046071, 38.8976983725056, 39.5507993568616, 40.0165489147731, 
    40.6098745547982, 41.6816796871757, 42.7349433933024, 43.694116279649, 
    44.6978439365385, 45.4754768882506, 45.8371730689935, 46.7041922994966, 
    47.6625349727275, 48.4476398424809, 49.4090266304694, 50.4113705988327, 
    101.667696, 102.109359, 102.345981, 102.622484, 103.240178, 
    103.329322, 103.508073, 103.4271, 103.393488, 103.377329, 
    102.695937, 101.857882, 101.252134, 101.295531, 101.59385, 
    102.200075, 102.866779, 102.131603, 102.196383, 264.333333333333, 
    253.75, 268.083333333333, 245.75, 255.166666666667, 258.833333333333, 
    254, 263.416666666667, 264.333333333333, 262.166666666667, 
    275.75, 287.916666666667, 279.416666666667, 283.666666666667, 
    364.25, 366.75, 306.583333333333, 301.833333333333, 358.75, 
    14.3103989361702, 18.295156626506, 22.3649880668258, 23.826140776699, 
    28.2539671361502, 29.3859846547315, 30.5744572748268, 31.2360814249364, 
    27.4194019138756, 27.6128148148148, 25.7981572481572, 20.134243902439, 
    22.5551535087719, 26.4484615384615, 28.7856198347107, 28.4003557312253, 
    33.7766602316602, 28.5684267241379, 30.4364462809917), dim = c(19L, 
    5L), dimnames = list(NULL, c("IIR", "MBR", "CPI", "WHT", 
    "WTI")), index = structure(c(915148800, 922924800, 930787200, 
    938736000, 946684800, 954547200, 962409600, 970358400, 978307200, 
    986083200, 993945600, 1001894400, 1009843200, 1017619200, 
    1025481600, 1033430400, 1041379200, 1049155200, 1057017600
    ), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts", "zoo"
    )))

structure(c(0, 0.1062173, 0.1883998, 0.1033952, 0.445663, 0.4197663, 
0, 0.6621655, 0.6400166, 0.5123887, 0.07414336, 0.08450978, 0, 
0.14496766, 0.02597733, 0.01588464, 0.07693148, 0.06575524, 0, 
0.01597095, 0.4902057, 0.7323414, 0.0836794, 0.1116206, 0), dim = c(5L, 
5L), dimnames = list(c("CN", "EU", "RU", "TR", "US"), c("CN", 
"EU", "RU", "TR", "US")))
```

I do not understand how they are different with respect to [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BGVAR/BGVAR.pdf).

Comment: I'm afraid I can't access the sample data from my location, but can you check your data formatting and naming matches the requirements here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BGVAR/BGVAR.pdf  (page 6 - bgvar). In particular the dimensions, consistent T rows and avoidance of dots in column names.

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen I'm quite sure it does. I have used the same code to format and run bgvar on a subset of this data just a few days ago. I see no NaN, no dots, the same number of observations in each entity dataset. There are 15 entities and the weight matrix is 15x15 with the same names and ordering. However, it just won't start. Should I upload the data some place else?

Comment: I don't think there's anything specifically wrong with that host, I'm just not somewhere I can try to use it at present.   You may get more traction if you can use `dput()` to make the data more accessible directly from the post, but I don't think it's required by any measure.

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen I've put the data into the post. With fewer observations, the error still persists, so it probably counts as a reproducible example.

Comment: I've had a crawl over the `dput` and I can't see anything amiss, it all looks correctly laid out and named, I've checked the rowsums in the weights, it all looks ok.  Hopefully someone can come along and do some more in depth testing for you soon.

Comment: Do there even have to be differences in the structure of the data for such errors to occur? I have added a dput() of data that models correctly and can barely tell the datasets apart.

Comment: I might have misunderstood the error. 'endonr' appears to denote endogenous variables in the model, so there ,ay be something wrong with the variable list. However, when I run parts of utils.R where variable lists are read, it seems to work fine. Besides, I still have this dataset where things just work. What else can I do to debug?